# Can't send messages to kafka topics in docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have written a docker-compose.yml file to allow multiple services to be linked and started at once.

I have a jar that sends messages in JSON format to a kafka topic inside a container, only it happens that sometimes it is impossible to send the data to the topic and I get this error message

```
WARNING: Error sending message with key 1,667,770,078,000
Topic general-events not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "bitnami/zookeeper:latest"
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    expose:
      - '29092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: '1'


  init-kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    container_name: init-kafka
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list

      echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic general-events --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

      echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list

      kafka-console-consumer --topic general-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server kafka:29092
      "
    
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    hostname: influxdb
    volumes:
      - influxdb-storage:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: ["./entrypoint.sh"]
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT}:8086

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
      - kafka
    container_name: telegraf
    links:
      - influxdb
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment: 
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=earthWatch
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=telegraf
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=60b42f6f12a91425b4fc02d1dd4e44eff9231f737171da79a993055c3aa367ab
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:rw

  java:
    image: openjdk:15
    depends_on:
      - init-kafka
    container_name: data-source
    volumes:
      - ./earthWatch.jar:/usr/src/java 
    command: bash -c "java -jar /usr/src/java earthWatch.jar"

volumes:
  influxdb-storage:
```

My producer class config:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName());
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "general-events";
    private KafkaProducer<Long, String> kafkaProducer = null;
    private final String KAFKA_CLUSTER_ENV_VAR_NAME = "KAFKA_CLUSTER";

    public Producer() {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Kafka Producer running in thread {0}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();

        String defaultClusterValue = "172.21.0.4:29092";
        String kafkaCluster = System.getProperty(KAFKA_CLUSTER_ENV_VAR_NAME, defaultClusterValue);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Kafka cluster {0}", kafkaCluster);

        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaCluster);
        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer");
        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "0");

        this.kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(kafkaProps);

    }
```

And when I check the logs I know that the topic is successfuly created:

```
[2022-11-06 21:35:13,759] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:13,866] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:13,969] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:14,176] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:14,578] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:15,383] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:16,591] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:17,795] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-06 21:35:18,900] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.21.0.5:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Creating kafka topics
Created topic general-events.
Successfully created the following topics:
general-events
```

But it consume nothing a the end, any ideas of what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed by reading logs that sometimes the bootstrap-server adress change, which is problematic because I have a this line in my producer class:

```
String defaultClusterValue = "172.21.0.4:29092";
```

Which is now:

```
String defaultClusterValue = "kafka:29092";
```

to always point to the right address.
It solve the problem for me